# jQuery Countdown timer with mousemove

Tags: jquery, timer, countdown, mousemove

I am trying to create a web page with a timer that is about 60 seconds long and if the user moves the mouse they get one message and if they wait the full 60 seconds they get another message. I have this part working which you can see from the code that has been created below.

The part that I cant get working it to allow the user to try again so if they move the mouse then they get the chance to try letting the mouse stay still for another 60 seconds or even at the end where they get the win message they can try again also.

**Old Code - The Code:**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Timer</title>
<style>
.start{display:block;}
.oops{display:none;}
.end{display:none;}
.tryagain{ cursor:pointer; color:#0066FF;}
.startcount{ cursor:pointer; color:#0066FF;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="start">
<span class="startcount">Start text</span> || Can you wait???
<p class="countdown"></p>
</div>

<div class="oops">
opps you moved the mouse | Would you like to <span class="startcount">try again?</span>
</div>

<div class="end">
Well done you waited. | Would you like to <span class="startcount">try again?</span>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    var count = -1;
        countdown = null;

    $('.startcount').on('click', function(){
        count = 10;
        $('.start').css({'display':'block'});
        $('.end').css({'display':'none'});
        $('.oops').css({'display':'none'});
        if (countdown == null){
        countdown = setInterval(function(){
            $("p.countdown").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
            if(count > 0){
                count--;
            }
            if(count == 0){
                $('.start').css({'display':'none'});
                $('.end').css({'display':'block'});
                $('.oops').css({'display':'none'});
                clearInterval(countdown);
                countdown = null;
            }
            if(count > 1){
                $('html').mousemove(function(){
                    $('.oops').css({'display':'block'});
                    $('.start').css({'display':'none'});
                    $('.end').css({'display':'none'});
                    clearInterval(countdown);
                    countdown = null;
                }); 
            }else if(count == 0){
                $('html').mousemove(function(){
                    $('.oops').css({'display':'none'});
                    $('.end').css({'display':'block'});
                });
            }else{
                $('html').mousemove(function(){
                    $('.oops').css({'display':'none'});
                });
            }
            console.log(count);
            console.log(countdown);
        }, 1000);
        }
    });

});
</script>
</body>
```

**Fixed Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Timer</title>
<style>
.start{display:block;}
.oops{display:none;}
.end{display:none;}
.tryagain{ cursor:pointer; color:#0066FF;}
.startcount{ cursor:pointer; color:#0066FF;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="start">
<span class="startcount">Start text</span> || Can you wait???
<p class="countdown"></p>
</div>

<div class="oops">
opps you moved the mouse | Would you like to <span class="startcount">try again?</span>
</div>

<div class="end">
Well done you waited. | Would you like to <span class="startcount">try again?</span>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    var count = 3, 
    countdown = null, 
    counter;

    $('.startcount').on('click', function(){

        // on click displayes the start information
        $('.start').css({'display':'block'});
        $('.end').css({'display':'none'});
        $('.oops').css({'display':'none'});

        counter = count; // sets up the counter
        countdown = setInterval(function(){
            $("p.countdown").html(counter + " seconds remaining!");

            if(counter != 0){
                //checks for mouse movements
                $('html').mousemove(function(){
                    $('.oops').css({'display':'block'});
                    $('.start').css({'display':'none'});
                    $('.end').css({'display':'none'});
                    clearInterval(countdown); //clears the interval so that it does not run multiple times 
                });
            } else {
                $('html').unbind('mousemove'); //removes the mousemove bind to the html !this is important
                $('.start').css({'display':'none'});
                $('.end').css({'display':'block'});
                $('.oops').css({'display':'none'});
                clearInterval(countdown); //clears the interval so that it does not run multiple times 
                return false;
            }

            counter--; //removes 1 from the counter

        }, 1000);
        $('html').unbind('mousemove'); //removes the mousemove bind to the html !this is important

    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

In fact you wanne start a countdown, when countdown is active you want to say to the user, hey wait you little goat and when 60 second are done, another message ? Right ?

Comment: They click on the startcount span to stat the counter which works, when it reaches zero the text changes which also works. I am clearing the setInterval at that stage. When the user clicks on the startcount again it does not run the setInterval again

Comment: You have an example page where i can try some things ?

Comment: no example page but if you set up an empty HTML page on your desktop copy and paste the code make sure you have <HTML> at the top with a close at the bottom. You should be able to see the demo running.

Comment: I hvae pritty much everything working in that code it just needs to work when the user click on the try again button and work or not break. I am happy to share all of the code with everyone, encase someone else comes up with this problem.

Comment: I understand your problem but i can't see why..
He also calls the function again but not the timer like you said

Comment: I wonder if it is because the clearInterval is inside the setInterval. It looks like the clearInterval clears everything so that it is not able to re-build or reset the interval again when you click the start button so how do you get around that???

Comment: Try to do this. but i even did this             clearInterval(countdown);
            countdown = setInterval(function () {

Comment: Its because the countdown null value is not being passed out of the setInterval function when it is being set so its not resetting countdown properly no null

Comment: And same problem in JQ plugin :s

Comment: I got it working :) I want to paste the code in there but not sure where to do it

Comment: Hey user666 I have pasted in my updated code above in fixed code. Please have a look and let me know what you think. I think it is working quite well now. I managed to fix all of the broken elements. It did mean changing some of the code but it is also shorter which is a bonus